# Moq a retrieve of particular list item

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I currently have such a Moq expression

```
repo.Setup(r => r.GetProjectConfigurationById(It.Is<int>(s => s == response.Id))) 
    .Returns(response); // return response only if id matches setup one
```

As one can see, response is an object that has its own Id field.
Now I have a `List<responses>` and would like to transfer this expression into something that behaves as such:

- get any integer `Id`
- if `Id` is mathcing a `response.Id`, return that element of a list.
- optionally, if match is not found, return `null`

How I could do that with Moq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `It.IsAny<int>()` to match any parameter in `GetProjectConfigurationById`

There are also overloads of the `Returns` function where you can specify your custom condition using the parameter passed in to your `GetProjectConfigurationById` to look up the element by id or return null:

```
var responses = new List<Response>();
//...
repo.Setup(r => r.GetProjectConfigurationById(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns<int>(id => responses.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id));
```